# Color code appointments in Microsoft Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

How do you color code appointments?  Outlook 2007 enabled you to do this, which made it easy to identify at a glance the category any particular appointment were assigned (e.g., personal, work, political. etc.).

Comment: You can change their category.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach **Categories** to appointments, both new and existing.

You can do this by opening a new or existing appointment and looking for `Categorize`.

[image]
[image]

After selecting you should see a number of colors you can assigns to the appointment, which I believe is what you are looking for.

[image]

You can also edit the description of each category or even create your own in the settings after selecting `All Categories...`

[image]